# Using ansible variable inside gathered fact list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm stuck to get data from gathered fact, using calculated data as part of query.

I am using 2.9 ansible and here is my task

```
---
- hosts: ios
  connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:

    - name: CEF OUTPUT
      ios_command:
        commands: sh ip cef 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 | i nexthop
      register: cef


    - set_fact:
        reg_result: "{{  cef.stdout |string| regex_search('Tunnel[0-9]+')}}"

    - name: IT WORKS!
      debug:
        msg: "{{ reg_result }}"

    - name: MANUAL LIST
      debug:
         var:  ansible_facts.net_interfaces.Tunnel3.description

    - name: AUTO LIST
      debug:
         var:  ansible_facts.net_interfaces.[reg_result].description
```

and here is output

```
PLAY [ios] **********************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************
ok: [10.77.3.1]

TASK [CEF OUTPUT] ***************************************
ok: [10.77.3.1]

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************
ok: [10.77.3.1]

TASK [IT WORKS!] ****************************************
ok: [10.77.3.1] => {
    "msg": "Tunnel3"
}

TASK [MANUAL LIST] **************************************
ok: [10.77.3.1] => {
    "ansible_facts.net_interfaces.Tunnel3.description": "DMVPN via MTS"
}

TASK [AUTO LIST] ****************************************
fatal: [10.77.3.1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ansible_facts.net_interfaces.[reg_result].description}}"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/user/ansible/retry/ios_find_gw_int.retry

PLAY RECAP **********************************************
10.77.3.1                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

You see. Now I know that my default gateway is pointing to "Tunnel3", and it is possible to get some data placing this "Tunnel3" in {{ ansible_facts.net_interfaces.Tunnel3.description }} but how to get this automatically? And I feel such nested variable in the list is a very handy tool.

Comment: Vladimir, thank you. Especially for pointing to the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dot if you use the indirect addressing

```yaml
    - name: AUTO LIST
      debug:
         var:  ansible_facts.net_interfaces[reg_result].description
```

See [Referencing key:value dictionary variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables).